# Function prints infinitely when in loop, although it's not called repeatedly

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to solve [a problem on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/printing-pattern-2/) where I have to print a pattern. Everything works as it's intended right now, except for the call of my loop function `repeat_number` inside the loop (!). It prints numbers infinitely, although it should only print it a fixed number of times.

This does not happen, when I call the function before the loop starts. When I print an integer variable it also prints only once. The error only occurs when I call `repeat_number` inside the loop.

Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void repeat_number(int number_to_repeat, int times_to_repeat) {
    for (int e; e < times_to_repeat; e++) {
        printf("%d ", number_to_repeat);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // Complete the code to print the pattern.
    
    // get number of rows
    int rows = n * 2 - 1;
    int starting_number = n;
    
    // print row after row
    for (int r; r < rows; r++) {
        // count down
        for (int i = rows; i > 0; i--) {
            if (starting_number >= 1) {
                printf("%d ", starting_number);
                if (starting_number > 1) {
                    starting_number--;                
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // repeat number
        repeat_number(5,1);
        
        // test 
        //int test = 2;
        //printf("%d", test);

        // count up
        for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
            if (starting_number >= 1) {
                if (starting_number < n) {
                    starting_number++;                
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
                printf("%d ", starting_number);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unitialised variable resulting in Undefined Behaviour: `for (int e;` -> `for (int e = 0;` and same for `for (int r;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line looks very dangerous:

```
for (int e; e < times_to_repeat; e++)
```

I would replace it by:

```
for (int e = 0; e < times_to_repeat; e++)
```

Because: imagine that `e` get initialised as some very small number, then you can have an enormous loop: always initialise your variables!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. So if the variable is not initialised, it will get a random number assigned?

Comment: e will have whatever was last stored in that memory location.

Comment: Just in addition to it, it looks like the for loop with int r wasn't initialised properly either.